# How to exclude some elements on body mouse move?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two elements I want to add mousemove event to body but I want to exclude these elements. How can i achieve this with jQuery?

```
$("body").on("mousemove",function(){
    //dont run following code if mouse is on these elements
})
```

Comment: " i want to add mousemove event to body" don't do that! This will be fired thousand times and in 99.99% of case, uselessly

Answer (score 1):

You can select and cache the elements that should be excluded and use jQuery `.index()` method and `target` property of the `event` object.

```
var $blackList = $('#elem, #elem2, #elem3'),
       timeout = ''; 

$(document).on("mousemove", function(e) {
   // Removing last timout using ID returned by setTimeout(if any) 
   clearTimeout(timeout);  

   // Setting timeout using setTimeout function, 
   // so the handler is executed once during each specified duration   
   timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      // event.target returnes target element of the event
      // if the index of the element in jQuery collection(an array of elements) is -1
      // execute the specified code 
      if ($blackList.index(e.target) === -1) { 
          // ...
      }
   }, 50); // change the duration according to your needs
});
```

Comment: to prevent mousemove event happen to quickly

Comment: i dont know much about index method but i think it wont work if e.target is a child elemnt inside these two elements

Comment: @MehmanManafov Yes, in that case it won't work, it was only one way of doing this(_in case that you can select all the target elements_), you could also use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method.